# Firefox Isn't Working With Transitions

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to make my website browser compatible with transition grayfades on an image hover and it works in Chrome and Opera but not in Firefox and I don't know why because I have the browser-specific code for Mozilla browsers.

Here is my code (although the main code that you'll want to look at is the img and img:hover in the CSS):

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Basketball Uniforms 1/24/14</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        html { 
            background: url(assets/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        header {
            width: cover;

            padding: 2em;

            background-color: rgba(17, 40, 87, 0.85);

            border-radius: 0 0 2em 2em;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        h3 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;

            color: #FFBB00;
        }

        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;

            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0 2em;
        }

        td {            
            border-style: groove;
            border-width: 2em;
            border-color: rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.95);
            border-radius: 4em;

            padding: 4em;
        }

        .odd {
            background-color: rgba(242, 153, 51, 0.80);
            color: #22499C;
        }

        .even {
            background-color: rgba(51, 112, 242, 0.80);
            color: #FEBB2D;
        }

        img {
            width: 26em;
            height: 20em;

            border-radius: 1em;

            transition: filter 1.5s ease;
            -ms-transition: -ms-filter 1.5s ease;
            -o-transition: -o-filter 1.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 1.5s ease;
            -moz-transition: -moz-filter 1.5s ease;
        }

        img:hover {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
            -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: url(assets/grayscale.svg);
            filter: gray;
        }

        h4 {
            padding-top: 1em;

            text-align: center;
        }

        h5 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        footer {
            width: cover;

            padding: 2em;

            background-color: rgba(17, 40, 87, 0.85);

            border-radius: 2em 2em 0 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Basketball Uniforms Through the Ages</h1>
        <h2>Leo Alfred&#58; 1/24/2013</h2>
    </header>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/portland-trail-blazers/1970-trail-blazers-debut-road-uniform-vintage-retro-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1970.jpg" title="1970&#39;s Basketball" alt="1970&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Portland Trail Blazers</h4>
                <h5>1970 - 1971 Debut Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="even">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/golden-state-warriors/1980s-warriors-away-california-uniform-vintage-retro-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1980.jpg" title="1980&#39;s Basketball" alt="1980&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Golden State Warriors</h4>
                <h5>1980 - 1985 Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/milwaukee-bucks/1990s-bucks-road-uniform-throwback/">
                    <img src="assets/1990.jpg" title="1990&#39;s Basketball" alt="1990&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Milwaukee Bucks</h4>
                <h5>1993 - 2005 Road Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="even">
                <a href="http://uniformcritics.com/basketball/nba/la-clippers/2000s-clippers-away-uniform-red/">
                    <img src="assets/2000.jpg" title="2000&#39;s Basketball" alt="2000&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>LA Clippers</h4>
                <h5>2000 - 2009 Away Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="odd">
                <a href="http://www.spartanjerseys.com/michigan-state-basketball-jersey/2010-2011/">
                    <img src="assets/2010.jpg" title="2010&#39;s Basketball" alt="2010&#39;s Basketball">
                </a>

                <h4>Michigan State Spartans</h4>
                <h5>2010-2011 Uniform</h5>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
        <h2>An LFX Design Website</h2>
        <h3>&#169; 2014 LFX Design</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
```

I don't know what's going on because I have the:

```
-moz-transition: -moz-filter 1.5s ease;
```

and the:

```
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: To clarify even more when I hover over the picture it just disappears instead of transitioning to a grayfade.

Comment: can you provide a JSFiidle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this style:

```
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");

}
```

Comment: Do you have a blur svg?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox ( or Gecko rather) currently does not support CSS Filters like blur,greyscale etc.

Here is a great website that lists the history and current support for CSS Filters across all browsers so you can use it to see what browser support you are looking at before you add it to your website.

http://caniuse.com/css-filters

And here is a post on Mozilla Support where people have asked the same question as to when will Firefox support CSS Filters : http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972373

Hope that helps!